# Error TR command width :punct: param

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tr

I have the following command:

```
cat original.txt | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | tr -d [:digit:] | 
tr -d [:punct:] > preproces.txt
```

And the system returns me the following error.

> when translating, the only character classes that may appear in
>   replaceString are 'upper' and 'lower'

The problem is giving:

```
tr -d [:punct:]
```

What's the solution to this problem?

I have searched Google and StackOverflow and don't find an answer to this problem.

Tiny edit (but significant for cut&pasters):
Changed '--d' to '-d' before [:punct:]
the '--d' was being rendered as '\342\200\223d' 
and the rendered difference was nearly invisible to the eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command :

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < original.txt  |
    tr -d '[:digit:]' |
    tr –d '[:punct:]' > preproces.txt
```

This avoid the infamous *useless use of cat* :

http://iki.fi/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Now, besides the already mentioned error, there is another error:
tr: extra operand <<original.txt>>

Comment: `tr` is purely a filter, it does not take file arguments: `tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' < original.txt |...`

Comment: The doubled brackets don't do what you think they do.  Try feeding some array references through your code.

Comment: @sputnick I tried again with the modification that you put on your response and I keep getting the same error message: tr: when translating, the only character classes that may appear in
string2 are `upper' and `lower'

Answer (score 2):

You only get the message you said you're seeing when you try something like:

```
tr '[:alpha:]' '[:digit:]'
```

I was able to use

```
tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

to delete punctuation without a problem.  For example:

```
$ echo "tr '[:alpha:]' [:digit:] <chkit.sh" | tr -d '[:punct:]'
tr alpha digit chkitsh
$
```

This was on RHEL 5 for x86/64 (`tr` version 'tr (GNU coreutils) 5.97').

You might note I enclosed the arguments to `tr` in quotes (single or double would do, though single are generally safer).  If you have any single-letter file names lurking in your directory, you could run into problems with the shell interpreting square brackets as character classes, and passing those names to `tr`.  Say you had a file `p`:

```
tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
```

That command is now `tr p [:lower:]`.  The error you get is slightly different, but it might be that your problem is related to that.  Be very careful with shell metacharacters; quotes are your friend.

Note that doubled square brackets are not part of the solution:

```
$ echo "tr -d '[[:alpha:]]' <chkit.sh" | tr -d '[[:alpha:]]'        
 - '::' <.
$
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't underestand your answer. What's the solution?. My TR version is 7.0.

Comment: I don't have GNU `tr` 7.0 compiled up and I'm not planning to change that. I found a copy of 8.12, as well as 5.97, and they work the same way. It is very unlikely there's a bug in `tr`. So, with that said, I'm saying and demonstrating that `tr -d '[:punct:]'` works fine.  Try it on its own.  The third code block echoes some text to `tr -d '[:punct:]'` and shows it works.  You should try it for yourself. I have two possible guesses as to your problem. One is "you left out the quotes". The other is that your question originally split the `tr` from the `[:punct:]` in its formatting. (continued)

Comment: (continuation): That is, when I formatted the question, there was part of the last `tr` command on one line and part on the next line.  I think that was probably irrelevant; that's why I didn't mention until now.  And what you had would not, I think, have generated the error you report.  So: I think that you've not yet accurately described all the circumstances of your problem.  Split it up into small pieces, like the `echo` lines I show, and work out what is going wrong.  And please do enclose the arguments to 'tr' in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If your `tr` does not support the `[:digit:]` and `[:punct:]` character classes, you will have to specify them explicitly.

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < original.txt  |
    tr -d '0-9!"#$%&'"'"'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~-' > preproces.txt
```

(The refactoring to merge the two `tr -d` commands into one could have been done by `tr -d '[:digit:][:punct:]'` in the original command, too.)

<sub>The definition of `[:punct:]` was obtained from http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html -- I have not attempted any verification, though I refactored it slightly to make it compatible with `tr` and the shell context it occurs in here.</sub>